# mdf can not open because version is 661 and my database support 665

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS 2019 latest version. I want to attach my MDF file can not open because it is version 661.This server supported only 665 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.Could not open in new database.

Answer (score 4):

The message means: your database file `.mdf` was created in a SQL Server **2008 R2** instance (internal version 661), and your installed SQL Server is version **2008** (I'm assuming it's really 655 - not 665).

This will **NOT WORK** - there's no trick, no method, no workaround, no hack to make this work - just does not work ever.

What you need to do is upgrade all SQL Server instances to the **same version** of the server - and quite honestly, with 2008 and 2008 R2 being **out of extended support** - I would **strongly recommend** you upgrade to a **currently supported** version of SQL Server - 2016, 2017 or 2019 would be best.

And SSMS is just the GUI frontend tool - it has no bearing on what the **internally supported** database file versions are.

Comment: that means my data file is not open in any way

Comment: It means you need to upgrade to a supported version @PAWANRAJBHAR .

Comment: @PAWANRAJBHAR: it *can be opened* by any version of SQL Server that is **2008 R2 or NEWER** - but not by SQL Server 2008

Comment: actually i am using ssms-2019 version it not supported in this version